# Prove $3^{rd}$ degree polynomial, $f \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}[x]$ if it has no roots in $\mathbb{F}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, irreducible-polynomials

I have a proof quickly sketched for this problem that I believe makes sense, the only trouble is that I feel as though I'm not addressing the specific fact that $f$ is a $3^{rd}$ degree polynomial and am hoping someone can point out where I'm missing that or how the degree, in this case, is relevant to the rest of the statement.

The only facts I refer to in the proof are the following Proposition and Corollary:

> Proposition: For any field $\mathbb{F}$ and $f,g \in \mathbb{F}[x]$, we have $deg(fg) = deg(f) + deg(g)$

> Corollary: For every $f \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$, there exists a polynomial $q \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ so that $f = (x -\alpha)q + f(\alpha)$. In particular, $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ iff $(x-\alpha) \mid f$

---

**My proof**

We proceed with proof by contrapositive. Assume $f$ has a root $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$. Then the Corollary states $(x-\alpha) \mid f$, hence $f = (x-\alpha)q$ where $q \in \mathbb{F}[x]$. We see that $f$ is a product of $2$ factors: a linear polynomial ($x-\alpha)$ and another polynomial $q$ whose order must be $2$ by the Proposition: $3 = deg(f) = deg((x-\alpha)q) = deg(x-\alpha) + deg(q) = 1 + 2$. This shows that neither factor is a constant and hence $f$ is not irreducible. $\square$

---

It feels like my inclusion of the degree of $f$ is merely incidental and not a core aspect of the proof. I welcome anyone to please enlighten me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your proof is correct, and it actually shows that if $\deg P(x)>1$ and if $P(x)$ has some root in $\Bbb F$, then $P(x)$ is reducible. If you are dealing only with polynomials whose degree is $2$ or $3$, then $P(x)$ is reducible if and only if it has some root in $\Bbb F$.

Comment: I think that'd what threw me off. It felt like my proof would be better suited for a generalization of the statement, rather than the specific case where $def(f) = 3$. I guess I thought that there would be something peculiar about the degree being $3$ that I would need to leverage.

Comment: You have stated the relevant facts but linked them together in the wrong order. You should start by assuming you are given a factorisation of $f$ as $gh$ say, then observe that as $f$ has degree $3$, one of $g$ and $h$ must have degree $1$, say $g = x - \alpha$ for some $\alpha \in \Bbb{F}$, and conclude that $\alpha$ is a root of $f$. The contrapositive then gives the result you state in the title of your question.

Comment: P.S., in future, please don't to rely on the title of your MSE questions for important information: make the body of your questions self-contained. There are several reasons for this: one is that some MSE interfaces, like the Android app don't render MathJax in the title.

Comment: that is NOT the contrapositive of what you have to prove

Comment: @Exodd You're correct. I literally glanced the problem and saw the second statement and linked that with the conclusion (i.e., $Q$ in $P \rightarrow Q$) where of course the conclusion "$f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is predicated on the premise which is that $f$ has no root in $\mathbb{F}$ so my contrapositive would start by assuming $f$ is reducible and then show that implies it has a root in $\mathbb{F}$, correct?

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you for your clarification, I seemed to just glance at the problem and switched the premise and conclusion. And thank you for letting me know about not relying on the title to convey the substance of my question. I only ever access this site on my PC so I had no idea about the typesetting not rendering on mobile.

Comment: exactly. can you conclude the proof by yourself now?

Comment: @Exodd Yes I can, and have. Thank you for your help and your insight. Be well!